# Existence of solution system of equations using Brower's fixed point theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to prove using the Brower's fixed point theorem that the following system of equations have at least one solution in $\{(x,y): |x|\le1  ; |y|\le1\}$.

$x-\frac{(y+1)^3}{10}=0$

$y-\frac{(x-1)^3}{10}=0$

To prove this I know I need a function that maps the domain into itself. In this case, I was thinking $f: [-1,1]^2 \rightarrow [-1,1]^2$. Defining

$f(x,y)=(\frac{(y+1)^3}{10},\frac{(x-1)^3}{10})$

However, in this case, for $|x|\le1$ we have $\sqrt[3]{-10}-1\le-1\le y \le 1 \le \sqrt[3]{10}-1$. (And almost symmetrical for $x$)

Is this enough to conclude that the Brower's fixed point theorem will work? If not, How can I "fix" the function $f$?

Thank you

Comment: Try restricting attention to the fourth quadrant only where $x\in[0,1], y\in[-1,0]$. I think your map $f$ maps this quadrant into itself.

Comment: If $|x|\le 1$ and $|y|\le 1$ then ${|y+1|^3\over 10}\le {8\over 10}\le 1$ and ${|x-1|^3\over 10}\le {8\over 10}\le 1.$